# Parallelization of for-loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to parallelize the following loop:

```py
L = []
for a in A:
    if condition:
        L += [a]
```

`A` can be very big (about 10^9 elements), however `L` in the end can be very small (about 100 elements). How can I parallelize this process?

I tried the following:

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed    
def function(a):
    if condition:
        return a
L = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(function)(a) for a in A)
```

But then most of the values in `L` are `None` because that way `L` has the same length as `A`. Of course, I could do

`L = [x for x in L if x is not None]`

afterwards. But this will go through the long list again. An alternative is

`L = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(function)(a) for a in A if function(a) is not None)`

but this also requires more computational time because of each `if`-check (`len(A)` such checks in total).

How can I create the `L` in a parallel process while  at the same time skipping the `None` values (i.e. appending only the values where the condition is true)?

Comment: There are two way to parallelize code in Python : using multithreading and multiprocessing. Multithreading will be useless here because of the GIL (unless your computation is IO bound which is not indicated, so probably not). With multiprocessing, you cannot share a list `L` efficiently. So basically there is no way to parallelise this loop as it is in pure-Python. You can however create process-local list and then concatenate them in the end. The multiprocessing overhead will be pretty big. It only worth it if the `condition` is particularly expensive.

Comment: Python is a mess for parallelism. It only provide basic parallelism feature mainly for embarrassingly parallel scripts. Anyway, if you have 1_000_000_000 items to compute in Python, this likely means you should not even use Python. Sending `A` to the multiple worker processes will likely be very expensive and take a lot of RAM. Please consider using a native code (or modules like Numpy if you can, especially vectorized calls). Cython can be a good start if you are not familiar with native languages like C/C++.

Comment: Actually, I'm doing this in Sage, but because of reasons of simplicity I have written a code (in pure Python) that is easily readable.

Comment: Parallelization works when each process is independent of another. But in your case they are dependent. Because the ouput list does not have the same length as the input, to which index each element in the output goes depends on the success of the previous steps.

Comment: Could `A` be perhaps automatically divided into several parts so that different lists can be created which then in the end could be concatenated together? I think `A` is not available as a list (because of limited memory), but it is possible to loop through it.

Comment: A billion elements isn't all that big, depending on what you're doing. As pointed out by others, Python probably isn't the platform to be doing this in, for many reasons. Many libraries for common data formats have optimised functions to do this for you (pandas, numpy, etc.) If your question isn't about Python, you shouldn't ask a question about Python - the right answer for one language is not going to be the right answer for another. Your suggestion to break up the work may work in some situations, but the answer remains "it depends".

Comment: You can get chunks of `A` and send them to processes using a round-robin strategy but this is slower than splitting basic lists which will be very expensive to send to processes here (due to the pickle/unpickle done by CPython internally). That being said, this has the benefit of using less RAM. Still I think using Python for such a task is clearly a dead end.

Comment: I'm using Sage and Sage is based on Python, so I thought the problem could be solved in Python. I'll try other systems.

Answer (score 1):

With the huge caveat that this is not a particularly efficient implementation, and folks have already talked about some of the concerns of doing this in the comments to your question, this is one way of doing it in pure Python using multiprocessing:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

from typing import (
    TypeVar,
    Callable,
)

T = TypeVar("T")


def process_large_input(
    A: list[T],
    filter: Callable[[T], bool],
    workers: int = mp.cpu_count(),
) -> list[T]:
    """
    Processes a large input list into a filtered list using multiprocessing.

    Arguments:
        A: The large input list.
        filter: The filter function.
        workers: The number of workers to use.
    """
    queue: mp.Queue[T] = mp.Queue()

    def worker(A: list[T], q: "mp.Queue[T]") -> None:
        """
        The worker function.

        Arguments:
            A: The large input list.
            filter: The filter function.
            sender: The sender connection.
        """
        for a in A:
            if filter(a):
                q.put(a)

    processes = [
        mp.Process(
            target=worker,
            args=(
                A[i::workers],
                queue,
            ),
        )
        for i in range(workers)
    ]

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    return list(queue.get() for _ in range(queue.qsize()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import math

    large_input = list(range(1, 1_000_001))

    def filter_func(x: int) -> bool:
        return math.log2(x) % 1 == 0

    print(process_large_input(large_input, filter_func))
```

Keep in mind though that it might save you less time than you think (depending, of course, on how computationally expensive the filtering function is):

```py
from timeit import timeit

print(
    "Timing parallel",
    timeit(lambda: process_large_input(large_input, filter_func), number=100),
) # Timing parallel 19.918051869999545 on my machine
print(
    "Timing sequential",
    timeit(lambda: [x for x in large_input if filter_func(x)], number=100),
) # Timing sequential 17.486059503000433 on my machine
```

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that this will get less and less efficient the more elements of A you can find in your resulting list, since synchronizing the queue is not cheap. Ultimately this is likely not the right tool for the job

Comment: Thank you very much! I get "Timing parallel 43.35731065319851 Timing sequential 111.52302265586331". I will try to apply it to my problem.

Comment: I get an error at `A[i::workers]` saying that `variable name 'slice(0, None, 12)' is not alphanumeric`. I'm dealing with matrices.

Comment: You'll have to devise your own way of splitting it into an appropriate number of workers if you're not working with just a plain list. Without knowing a little more specifically about how things are implemented it is hard to say